# Initial guess for Newton Raphson

Tags: algorithm, math, newtons-method

How can I determine the initial guess of the equation `Ax+Bsin(x)=C` in terms of A,B and C ?
I am trying to solve it using Newton Raphson. A,B and C will be given during runtime.

Is there any other method more efficient than Newton Raphson for this purpose ?

Comment: I think this should be on http://math.stackexchange.com/?as=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal initial guess is the root itself, so finding an "optimal" guess isn't really valid.

Any guess will give you a valid solution eventually as long as `f'(x0) != 0` for any step, which only occurs at the zeroes of `cos(x)`, which are `k*pi + pi/2` for any integer `k`.

I would try `x0 = C * pi`, just to see if it works.

Your biggest problem, however, would be the periodic nature of your function. Newton's method will be slow (if it even works) for your function as `sin(x)` will shift `x0` back and forth over and over.

---

**Precaution:**

[image]

In Newton's method, do you notice how `f'(xn)` is in the denominator? `f'(x)` approaches `0` infinitely many times. If your `f'(x) = 0.0001` (or anywhere close to zero, which has a chance of happening), your `xn+1` gets thrown really far away from `xn`.

Worse yet, this can happen over and over due to `f'(x)` being a periodic function, which means that Newton's method might never even converge for an arbitrary `x0`.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is http://www.spoj.pl/problems/TRIGALGE/ . Now I see the problem with the Newton Raphson's approach. Normal Bisection gives TLE(Time limit exceeded). Now I am thinking of mixing Bisection with Newton Raphson's. Is there any better approach ?

Comment: I would first try Bisection for a few iterations to find a decent guess for Newton's method and then use Newton's method for a more accurate approximation.

Comment: The statement that *any* guess will give a valid solution is incorrect: see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_of_the_method_to_converge_to_the_root) for example. The statment that `f'(x)` approaches zero infinitely many times is also not *per se* correct -- that depends entirely on the value of `A` (and if `B = 0`, there is no obviously periodic component). The whole question is ill-posed, since there might be infinitely many solutions, and the usefulness of each one is not indicated by the OP. Just saying.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I didn't give my answer too much thought when writing it, so I did overlook a few details and assumed some things that I shouldn't have.

Comment: Well, it's been a while, and, I understand your position completely given the OP at the time. I commented mainly to make random passers-by more aware of the shortcommings in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest "good" approximation is to just assume that sin(x) is approximately zero, and so set:

```
x0 = C/A
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if A,B and C are real and different from 0, then `(B+C)/A` is an upper quote to the highest root and `(C-B)/A` is a lower quote to the lowest root, as `-1 <= sin(x) <= 1`. You could start with those.

Answer (score 0):

Newton method can work with any guess. the problem is simple,
if there is an equation and I guessed x0=100
and the best close solution for it is x0=2
and I know the answer is 2.34*
by using any guess in the world you will eventually get to 2.34*
the method says to choose a guess because without a valid guess it will take many solutions which aren't comfortable no one wants to repeat the method 20 times
 and guessing a solution is not hard 
you just find a critical point-
for example, 3 is too big and 2 is too small
so the answer is between 2 and 3
but if instead guessing 2 you guess 50
you will still get to the right solution.
like I said it will just take you much longer
I tested the method by myself
I guessed 1000 to a random equation
and I knew the best guess was 4
the answer was between 4 and 5
I chose 1000 it took me much time 
but after a few hours, I got down from 1000 to 4.something
if you somehow can't find a critical point you can actually put a random number equals to x0 and then eventually you will get to the right solution 
no matter what number you guessed.

Comment: Please format your answer better. It is really hard to follow your thoughts.